# Observing TypeError: Not sure how to fix this error

Tags: python

My requirement is to add the digits in an integer received as an input from the user. The integer is first converted to String and then the string is converted to list. After converting the string to list, I am iterating through each element in the list and performing a sum to display the final result.

I have seen some simple programs in the internet which uses 'map' and 'sum' command to get the final result. I wanted to use a list to iterate the elements.
Can someone please help me find out the mistake in the program?

```
number=int(input("Enter the number:"))  
total=0  
mystr=str(number)  
mylist=list(mystr)  
print mylist  
for element in mylist:  
    total=total+element  
print total
```

I am observing the below mentioned error,

```
RESTART: C:\SKANAKAV\at&t\Python\Aricent_Python\python_scripts\Find the Sum of Digits in a Number\test_map.py 
Enter the number:234
['2', '3', '4']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SKANAKAV\at&t\Python\Aricent_Python\python_scripts\Find the Sum of Digits in a Number\test_map.py", line 16, in <module>
    total=total+element
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Hi, if you feel an answer solved your problem please accept it by clicking on the green check mark next to it 

Answer (score 0):

use `total = total + int(element)`

Comment: The below script works perfectly:                                                                         number=int(input("Enter the number:"))
total=0
mystr=str(number)
mylist=list(mystr)
print mylist
for element in mylist:
    total = total + int(element)
print total

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through your list, the elements are still strings.
That's what's throwing the error. You need to convert to an integer before adding it up.

Also, your input comes in as a string, but then you convert it to an integer, and then immediately convert it back to a string. Just skip those conversions.

This code will do what you want:

```
number=input("Enter the number:")
mylist=list(number)
total=0
print(mylist)
for element in mylist:
    total += int(element)
print(total)
```